# Give program access to only directories below cwd

Tags: permissions, security, sudo, chmod, access-control

Say I run a program like so:

```
cd foo && program x y z
```

How can I give `program` access to only the directories in `foo` and below?

Pretend my fs looks like:

```
$HOME/
  foo/
  bar/
  baz/
```

if I run `program` in the `foo/` dir, it obviously shouldn't have access to what's in `bar/` or `baz/`, etc.

**NOTE:** My distro is Ubuntu 16.04 if that makes any difference.

Comment: One way - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105/chroot-jail-what-is-it-and-how-do-i-use-it. Might be more work than what you want.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384117/linux-isolate-process-without-containers.

Comment: None of those answers seem very good. Be brave and post  one here and collect points.

Comment: Here's more resources to look into - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64642/how-to-prevent-a-process-from-writing-files & https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6433/how-to-jail-a-process-without-being-root.

Comment: Take a look at this Q, I think it solves your issue - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153665/per-process-private-file-system-mount-points, if so I'd call your Q a duplicate of it.

Comment: its kinda crazy that linux doesnt support this out of the box

Comment: I would argue that it does, that `unshare` command was on my CentOS 7.x by default. `unshare` cmd is in `util-linux-2.23.2-43.el7_4.2.x86_64`. Thats part of defs. I've never contemplated using `chroot` or any of this directly, usually just go to a `docker` container instead.

Comment: Why won't standard file system permissions work for you? Simple, well understood, effective.

Comment: @roaima sure if you can do that in a short bash script, please feel free to demonstrate. What I am looking for is a simple unix feature like so `run x`, where `run` is a program that will give the `x` executable only permissions to directories below cwd, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good answer:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384120/113238

so we'd do something like this:

```
chown app1 /var/lib/myapps/app1
chmod 700 /var/lib/myapps/app1
sudo -u app1 /var/lib/myapps/app1/run.sh
```

*however, I'd to find a solution that does not require sudo.*

Comment: This does not stop the application from _accessing_ (reading) files elsewhere on the system. It only provides a directory that the application can write to, in a fashion very similar to how most daemons are running under special system accounts on most modern Unices.

Comment: ok I am just looking for answers to the OP that are reasonable, I don't think it should be so hard to find one but it is

Comment: This is usually what a chroot is for, executing a process with a displaced root directory.